# node.js creating jobs with ttl using redis

Tags: node.js, redis, jobs, job-scheduling

I need to design a node.js app in this scenario:

1. User requests to /page with a cookie which has a unique `token`
2. Node.js creates a `record` with this token on redis(?) with a 5 mins TTL. `token`s has `n` type. So redis(?) should store tokens with types.
3. If user comes back again before `record` expire, `record`'s TTL reset to 5 mins again.
4. If user doesn't come back again and `record` expires, a function is triggered.
5. And at last, I **also** need the count of `record`s belongs to a specific type (i.e. type 27).

What would be the best way to achieve this problem? Is redis right choice for it? How can I count `token`s and trigger 5. step if I use redis?
Using https://github.com/Automattic/kue or something like that would be the nice choice?

Edit:
It seems possible duplicate with [Event on key expire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647494/event-on-key-expire)
. In general, I ask, is redis suitable for this problem? If you think it is, could you please give an example pattern I should follow. If not, what are any other solutions maybe even without redis or 3rd party tool.

Also as I said at the 5. item in the list above, redis seems not suitable at querying `keys` with a pattern as described here:https://redis.io/commands/keys
. Because there seems no way to put expiration on an individual member of a set ([TTL for a set member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17060672/ttl-for-a-set-member)) , I cannot put tokens in a `type` set or hash . Thus I need to query keys in order to get count of a group (`type`) and this seems not efficient as described at the link above.

Even if https://redis.io/topics/notifications solves the problem at the 4. item in the list above, I also ask for "Which pattern/algorithm should I go and how" . I don't want you to code for me, but just need a spark. A tutorial, guide, video etc.. would be great. Thanks!

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I've just created redis strings but I saw I don't know how to "trigger a function when the key expired" and also getting count of record (keys) which has type, say 27, is also seems not efficient with redis. I just found this links:
https://redis.io/commands/keys

https://quickleft.com/blog/how-to-create-and-expire-list-items-in-redis/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33166812/redis-scan-count-how-to-force-scan-to-return-all-keys-matching-a-pattern

Comment: Since there is really nothing else except **get notified when redis key expires**. Possible duplicate of [Event on key expire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647494/event-on-key-expire)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many options in order to achieve what you want, but I'm going to provide one here, which is a very efficient one in terms of retrieving speed, but it requires some more space. It all depends on your use-case, obviously.

Say token is 12345, type is A

When adding a token (we'll do it with a transaction):

```
MULTI
SETEX tokens:12345 300 ""
SET type:12345 "A"
INCR types:A
EXEC
```

When the key expires (after 300 seconds, or whenever Redis sees it as expired) we get notified using Keyspace notifications (https://redis.io/topics/notifications) listening for the EXPIRED event:

```
PSUBSCRIBE __keyspace@0__:expired
```

When that subscription receives a message, in your code you'd need to:

```
MULTI
GET type:12345 # Returns A
DEL type:12345
DECR types:A
EXEC
```

In order to get the elements of a specific type:

```
GET types:A
```

Any NodeJS Redis client would work just fine for this.

I want to make clear this is only one of the multiple options you have; one of the Redis advantages is it's flexibility.

Comment: That is it! Thank you for your guidance. I will give it a try and write here if I stuck at any point.

Comment: No problem, let me know if you need any help

Comment: I think `__keyspace@0__:expired` should be change with `__keyevent@0__:expired`

Comment: could be, sorry